# 'e+0' notation in columns with S-specifier

Tags: tables, siunitx

I know it sounds silly but I want to have the scientific notation `e+0` in a table with S specified columns. Currently it gives me only `e0`. It just looks better in my table to have the zero with sign, for symmetry reasons.

Here is a wee example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
% To increase space of some rows in tables, especially needed in header row before \hline
\newcommand\T{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}       % Top strut
\newcommand\B{\rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % Bottom strut

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\footnotesize
\sisetup{output-exponent-marker = \text{e},exponent-product = {},retain-explicit-plus,retain-zero-exponent,table-format=+1.4e+2}
\begin{tabular}{llSS}
MRE Sample & $N$ & {$\mu_1 [Pa]$} & {$\alpha_1 [-]$}   \B \\  \hline
{Isotropic $10\%$ MREs} & 1 & 1.5030e+05 & 4.2384e+00 \T \\ 
& 2 & 6.7175e+05 & 8.4376e-01 \\
& 3 & 6.7175e+05 & 8.4376e-01  \B \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption[]{Scientific notation $e0$ instead of $e+0$}
\label{tab:example}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Many thanks for your help.
Gerlind

Comment: I tried the same and concluded that removing `e0` was better. `;-)` Don't use the `center` environment nested in `table`; just declare `\centering`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a very ugly solution which will do your job but I'm almost ashamed to suggest.

Define:

```
\def\fix#1{\sisetup{output-exponent-marker=\text{e+}}#1}
```

and then use `\fix{4.2384e+00}` instead of `4.2384e+00` in your table.

If one is looking for a real solution, I'd think this would involve redefining the `\siunitx_number_process_exponent` macro and doing a very small change there
(around line 1800 of `siunitx.sty`).
I tried doing this but soon gave up, as everything in this file seems to be defined using experimental LaTeX 3 notation and I'm not familiar at all with this. Sorry...

Comment: It is tedious for large tables but it works. Thanks.

Comment: better use: `\def\fix#1{\sisetup{output-exponent-marker=\mathrm{e+}}#1}`